# Linux server only shows source code of php not actual site

Tags: linux, php

I am kind of trying to transfer my website to an Amazon EC2 instance. I have set up everything and now when I open my website instead of seeing the website I just get to see the source code.

Is there anything I did wrong in the setup process ?

Comment: have you installed php?

Comment: No I haven't. How do I do that ?

Comment: read my answer, it will help to configure whole server and PHP, MySQL too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run php of Amazon EC2, you must have to follow this steps

**Configuring PHP**

First, the basics for PHP:

```
sudo yum install php-mysql php php-xml php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-cli mysql httpd
```

Press `y` for each of the prompts that shows up. Note that you’re logged in as `ec2-user`, so you need to sudo all of these commands.

You should now be able to create and run a PHP test file. Next, let’s get MySQL up and running.

Want more details read this article : [Getting PHP and MySQL running on Amazon](http://www.alexkorn.com/blog/2011/03/getting-php-mysql-running-amazon-ec2/)

Comment: very nice thanks very much ! I now have a web server running and installed php and mysql, but where do I upload my files, or more specifically, how do I do that ? I guess into the var/www/html folder, is that correct ?

Comment: great! yah you can upload it in var/www/html or create new folder inside ec2-user folder like public_html

Comment: you can upload it in any directory but make sure you must have to specify path in `httpd.conf` file

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much Sumit ! One more thing: If I wanted to add files to the folder via a ftp client how would I do that ?

Comment: you can't access you ftp but you can do it via sftp.

Comment: read this it will help - http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20111012-0812

Comment: Host is your `Elastic IP address`, user name is `ec2-user` and no need of password last port no is `22`

Answer (score 6):

You can't run PHP code from S3 at all -- it's just a storage service and a web server, it doesn't include a PHP application server. As the other answer states, you can set up an instance in EC2 and run a web application there, but EC2 and S3 are two different services.

Comment: Thank you, I was not quite sure how these two services work together. Now I know they don't. Useful ! Thanks